# Macro (?) to have users select print range

Tags: excel, printing, range

I have created a 6 sheet workbook.  Each sheet contains a 52 week schedule for a specific workgroup in my department.  I have named each range for each schedule but would like to come up with an automated way for the users to select the workgroup and week to print instead of finding (there are 312 names in the list) the named area and using "print selection" option.  Any ideas?  Please keep in mind that I am in no way a programmer and will need spoon fed on this.

Comment: Are you saying there are 312 different print ranges?

Comment: Yes there are.  That is why I don't want the users to have to pick from the list to find the range.  Is there a way to put a "print button" next to each weekly schedule that when clicked would automatically select the correct range to print?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create named ranges under Formulas, Define Name.
This allows you to assign a unique name to a cell range.
Once the named ranges are created, users can select the name from the dropdown list found to the left of the address bar. Selecting the name will jump to the range. Then you could have a button on the Quick access toolbar that they click that would print the selection.

You can create the macro to print selection by turning on the macro recorder then linking the code to a button you add to the quick access toolbar. Optionally, you can put a button (i.e. textbox that you assign a macro to) on the page to print the area selected.

Comment: I think that the option to put a text box with a macro next to the print area is a good idea.  I just don't know how to do it.  Can you explain?

Comment: ok, I figured this out just by playing around.  Thanks for putting me on the right track!